# NestedScrollView don`t scroll above 8 items

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I was looking for a solution on the Internet, but did not find.

When i`m trying scrolling.

Scroll stops on 8 item and part 9 item.

I use NestedScrollView and tried ViewPager, but no much results

Sorry i`am very bad in English, because i`m newbe.

I will be very grateful for your help.

How me change code xml to view all items on scrolling?

Below is my code

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <eu.kanade.tachiyomi.widget.ElevationAppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ActionBar.Tab"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabMinWidth="75dp">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </eu.kanade.tachiyomi.widget.ElevationAppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <com.bluelinelabs.conductor.ChangeHandlerFrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/controller_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

items.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<eu.kanade.tachiyomi.widget.RevealAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/reveal_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/toolbar_bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        tools:listitem="@layout/chapters_item"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<eu.davidea.fastscroller.FastScroller
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fast_scroller"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    app:fastScrollerBubbleEnabled="false"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    style="@style/Theme.Widget.FAB"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_24dp"/>
```